# i need help creating a balloon animation for my app

Tags: android, animation, button

Well I don't have much android experience let alone android animation and I need to make an animation that makes balloons fly up from the bottom of the screen on the touch of a button. I made the button but idk what I'm doing from this point on. So what I need to know is where I get the images where to put the images and how to make the images move(balloons being the images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [TranslationAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html):

```
  TranslateAnimation animate;
  animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0, -view.getHeight()); // <------  slide up
  animate.setDuration(200);
  animate.setFillAfter(true);
  balloonView.startAnimation(animate);
  balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This site looks like a great help but am I adding all of this code after my onclick or do I need to create a whole other class. Sorry for the ignorance I'm still very new to the programming world